# Object Reference Error when trying to check for activated features using windows forms app

Tags: feature, feature-activation

```
var feature = spSite.Features.SingleOrDefault(sf => sf.Definition.DisplayName.ToLower().Equals(strFeatureName));//Error block
     if (feature != null)//if feature is activated
      {   
       spSite.Features.Remove(feature.DefinitionId);//deactivate feature
       spSite.Features.Add(feature.DefinitionId);//activate feature
      }
```

I am using this code to check for activated features using a windows forms app. It is working fine in local but showing object reference error in DEV machine. 
I suspect the first line might be causing the error.

Can anyone figure out what would be causing the error and a workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

Try below

```
var feature = null;
if(spSite.Features != null) {
    feature = spSite.Features.SingleOrDefault(f => (f.Definition != null && f.Definition.DisplayName != null && f.Definition.DisplayName.ToLower().Equals(strFeatureName));
}
```